# Voice Over Accessibility with UI Automation

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, ios-ui-automation, voiceover

I am using voice over accessibility in my application. But When I am using UI Automation testing, It breaks the accessibility. Because Automation uses the accessibility class to show accessibilitylabel. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use **accessibilityIdentifier** instead.

It is not visible by Voice Over and can be accessed with method *name* from *UIAElement*.
And if left empty it will copy value from the label.

More on that [UIAccessibilityIdentification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityIdentification_Protocol/index.html)